# where are the revision logs for asmFish

Tags: engines, software, uci

Please help because I can't find the revision logs on any website.  I want to download version 051117 but I literally cannot get any website to have it.

Answer (score 1):

> https://github.com/lantonov/asmFish

gives you all the revision logs for each and every single commit. The version 051117 is just the latest version registered on 05.11.17.